# Python Run an encrypted program

Tags: python

I want to rent a program in Python but I don't want my customers to see the source code I made.

So, how do I let them run the file without seeing the source code? I was thinking about python-crypto AES But it requests a password to decrypt the code to run it, so.. any ideas?

Comment: Not really possible

Comment: The issue is key management. In order for the code to actually run, you need to have a key to decrypt it -- meaning that your customer necessarily has a way to reverse your encryption or they can't run your software. There are lots of obfuscation methods, but anything foolproof is literally impossible.

Comment: Keep in mind that a customer can run your code on a virtual machine and track literally every instruction that goes through the CPU, every piece of data in memory, etc. Heck, it takes considerably less investment than you might think to dump memory state in bulk at runtime from real hardware -- particularly if your software runs on systems with 4GB of RAM or less (meaning fitting inside the space addressable via Firewire). Your time is better spent building the best software you can, and relying on legal mechanisms to deal with reverse engineering.